# Using GoogleApiClient in Fragment Android

Tags: google-maps, fragment, android-context, google-api-client

I tried to load a Google map into a fragment. I don't know what the three lines should be... (the three lines commented with "problem!").

Most examples are using "this" in the parenthesis. I understand this is a fragment, not an activity, so I used "getActivity()" instead. But if I changed all three lines to getActivity(), it didn't work either. Please help! Thanks in advance!

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback,GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {
private static final String TAG = "***MapFragment***";
private final int PERMISSION_CODE = 1;
private GoogleApiClient myGoogleApiClient;
private GoogleMap myMap;
private Location curLocation;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_target, container, false);

// create api client
if (myGoogleApiClient == null) {
    myGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())  // problem!
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)   // problem!
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)  // problem!
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
}
```

Comment: U can use getActivity(), and u trying to build this after return ?

Comment: @Blackkara If I use getActivity() to the second line, it gives an error says "addConnectionCallbacks (com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks) in Builder cannot be applied to (android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity) "

Comment: and do it before return

Comment: do it before return makes no difference...

Comment: What error you giving ?

Comment: still the same error as in my last reply

Comment: Dont use getActivity() in second and third lines, use 'this'. I explained what they are in below answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here need context, u can use getActivity()

```
new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())  // problem!
```

Below two methods need callback, so your fragment must implement  ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener listeners.

```
.addConnectionCallbacks(this)   // problem!
.addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)  // problem!
```

**Explanation**

- .addConnectionCallbacks method needs ConnectionCallbacks
- .addOnConnectionFailedListener method needs OnConnectionFailedListener

You already implemented them

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback,
GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {
    ...
}
```

So, 'this' here **refers your MapFragment class**. And when u pass 'this' in above methods, they uses their callbacks.

Comment: I think I have implemented these two interfaces?

Comment: This works! Thank you! Could you explain what the "this" here stand for?